# If a sequence $X_n$ of RVs converges in probability to $X$, does the sequence $\mathbb{E}(X_n)$ also converge to $\mathbb{E}(X)$?

Tags: pr.probability, random-matrices, expectation

I couldn't find the answer in literature so any idea would be helpful.

Comment: This should actually have been posted to http://math.stackexchange.com instead as it is not research level.  I've voted to migrate it there.

Comment: (I forgot which site I was on - I wouldn't have answered the question if I had noticed it was on MathOverflow.)

Answer (score 1):

Not in general.  The standard counterexample is to let $U \sim U(0,1)$, $X_n = n 1_{\{U \le 1/n\}}$, and $X=0$.

There are several basic theorems giving sufficient conditions for this to hold, e.g. monotone convergence, dominated convergence, uniform integrability.  They can be found in any graduate-level probability textbook.

Comment: Thank you for the notice. What I am working on concretely are variables in form of `e^tXiY`, where t is a real number, and Xi, Yj are independent sequences of random variables having binomial distribution. How to figure out would the condition hold in this case?

Comment: Maybe look in the literature for results on sufficient conditions, as the answer suggests...